# Exact autocorrelation function evaluation in R

Tags: r

How do I overlay a true/population acf over the plot of a sample acf? Is there a function where all you have to do is specify the model, and it will overlay this function on top of a sample plot?

```
acf(arima.sim(n = 63, list(ar = c(0.8897, -0.4858), ma = c(-0.2279, 0.2488)),
     sd = sqrt(0.1796)))
# something goes here
```

Comment: You'll likely need to provide some more information here, such as actual population data and a sample taken from it. Does `arima.sim` facilitate this?

Comment: @r2evans yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I wanted `ARMAacf()`.

```
acf(arima.sim(n = 63, list(ar = c(0.8897, -0.4858), ma = c(-0.2279,0.2488)), sd = sqrt(0.1796))) 
lines(ARMAacf(ar = c(0.8897, -0.4858), ma =  c(-0.2279, 0.2488), lag.max = 17))
```